# C# .Net ¿ Como borrar los valores de una clase estática al cerrar pagina o recompilar proyecto?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo una clase estatica que la uso en una pagina web con C# .Net Webforms

La primera vez que compilo el proyecto las variables dentro de esta clase estatica estan a cero o sin asignar a ningun valor. En un momento dado mientras navego por la pagina alguno de los valores de esta clase se le van asignando valores y como es una clase estatica estos valores se conservan para diferentes paginas de la web.

Ahora el problema con que no contaba es que al cerrar el navegador o recompilar el proyecto, suponia que estos valores de la clase estaticas estarian otra vez a cero pero si debugo veo que las variables siguen conservando el valor anterior.

```
public static class Util
{
   public static string heNavegado = "";
}
```

inicialmente Util.heNavegado = "", al principio de la navegacion web Util.heNavegado toma el valor de "UN POCO", cuando llevo bastante tiempo le doy el valor de Util.heNavegado = "BASTANTE". En un momento dado termino la ejecucion del programa y lo vuelvo a lanzar recompilando el proyecto o volviendo a ejecutarlo  pero la variable Util.heNavegado sigue teniendo el valor "BASTANTE" en vez de ""

Comment: puede que el problema te venga del navegador, has mirado si limpiando la cache te lo conserva o se borra?

Comment: @NicolasOñate no funciona ni limpiando cache, ni cambiando de navegador a la hora de debugar. Lo que es extraño es que la clase no vuelva a inicializar la variable heNavegado a "" cuando lo declaras al inicio con un public static string heNavegado = "". Con esto al iniciar el programa la primera vez deberia igualarlo a ""

Answer (score 1):

Es correcto lo que te está pasando. Las variables estáticas una vez que tienen valor no lo pierden hasta que se finaliza la aplicación web (normalmente varias horas según esté configurado en el AppPool del IIS).

En general es mala idea usar una variable estática para guardar datos de un usuario concreto en una aplicación web, ya que se comparten entre todos los usuarios que están usando esa aplicación.

Tal vez la solución más sencilla es que le quites guardes el valor en un objeto "session" por ejemplo:

```
session["HeNavegado"] = true;
```

Así la aplicación enviará una cookie a tu navegador que te identificará ante el servidor.

Usar el objeto sessión es tal vez la solución más sencilla y rápida, pero trae algunos inconvenientes (por ejemplo su uso en un entorno clusterizado no es inmediato, o se produce un consumo de memoria en el servidor para guardar).

Comment: No se comparten las variables estaticas ya que cada usuario cuando accede a la web lo hace con una nueva instancia de esa web.

Comment: @Popularfan Mis pruebas dicen que si que se comparten. Además si no se compartiesen no tendría sentido esta pregunta.

Comment: Es correcto hay un cruce en el valor de las variables si uso variables estáticas globales. He vuelto a probarlo y falla por este tema. No se si hay otra solución mas aparte de usar variables de session